# Is there a county-level maps dataset that includes independent cities in virginia?

Tags: data, r, maps, united-states, ggplot2

The following code shows the dataset I am working with:

```
library(maps)
CountyMapData <- map_data("county")
head(CountyMapData)

       long      lat group order  region subregion
1 -86.50517 32.34920     1     1 alabama   autauga
2 -86.53382 32.35493     1     2 alabama   autauga
3 -86.54527 32.36639     1     3 alabama   autauga
4 -86.55673 32.37785     1     4 alabama   autauga
5 -86.57966 32.38357     1     5 alabama   autauga
6 -86.59111 32.37785     1     6 alabama   autauga
```

There are several cities in Virginia which are independent and not part of counties.  For example, Alexandria City and Bristol City. I would like to be able to have polygons for these too.

Is there a dataset such as the above that includes independent cities but is otherwise at the county-level?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use county shapefiles from the Census Bureau? The Census recognizes those independent Virginia cities as both cities and as independent counties for the purposes of geographic distinction. [Here](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/G001/0400000US51.05000) is a list of the areas designated at the county level by the Census Bureau for the state of Virginia. You can find shapefiles for all counties [here](ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/COUNTY/tl_2013_us_county.zip).

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with the resolution provided by the [GADM database](http://www.gadm.org), then you can easily download that data using the convenience function `raster::getData()`.

(**Do note:** In addition to loading US county-level data as a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to the current R session, the code below will also save the data for future use to a file named `USA_adm2.Rdata` and located in your current working directory.)

```
## Download the data
library(raster)
counties <- getData(name="GADM", country="USA", level=2)

## Extract and plot the Virginia counties & independent cities, to show this works
va_counties <- subset(counties, NAME_1=="Virginia")
va_ind_cities <- subset(va_counties, TYPE_2=="Independent City")
plot(va_counties)
plot(va_ind_cities, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

[image]